# Working on Wordpress with a Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm building a Wordpress site for a friend, and she asked me to "put the old site back up" while I'm working on the WP site.  The old site lives in a /verb subfolder, so I put a PHP redirect in the domain/index.php page to the domain/verb folder.

Now, when I go to work on the WP site, it just redirects to the old site.  Is there a better way to do this?  I need a way to develop the WP site while visitors are sent to the old site.

Note:  Her site is on godaddy, which means I didn't install WP myself and can't really move the WP installation to a sandbox area while I'm working on it.  Is there an .htaccess trick I could be doing, maybe?

Comment: A quick fix would be to put a check around the redirect. So if you pass a `?noredirect` get param it won't redirect you. Only problem is that it needs to be appended to ALL requests. I suppose you could set a session variable to keep it from redirecting.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while but I'm pretty sure i've used a plugin before that allowed me (when logged in as an admin in WP) to view the site using a different theme than the one the rest of the world is seeing.

You could copy the active theme and change the name, making your alterations on the new theme while leaving the currently active theme untouched.

This would only work if you were re-skinning the site and not modifying any of the database content.

A quick google search came up with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-test-drive/, but there may be others out there...

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this, but I hit the up button because it sure makes sense, and I feel like I've seen an option to change the admin theme somewhere.